# autocad sheet set manager view label block displays incorrect scale

Tags: autocad

I have been trying to use the sheet set manager in Civil 3D. When I add a view to the layout using stock callouts and view labels, the view label block which references the scale of the viewport will display 1"=3.3333333'. It should be 1" = 40' I drew a line 40' long in the source drawing and have confirmed that the viewport is displaying at the correct scale. Just to be clear I am using a relative scale not an absolute scale.  Obviously 40/12=3.333.  So it would seem to be an issue of an inch to feet scale factor.  Considering this I made a custom view label block to be used in the sheet set manager.  If the units of the block drawing are set to inches the block comes in normal size with the incorrect scale mentioned above.  If the block drawing units are set to feet, the block comes in smaller but still displays the same incorrect scale.

I also tried using different formats when inserting the field for the attribute definition when creating the view label block.  This gave different results such as 77/256" = 1' when using the "#"= 1'. The other formats all produced incorrect results. What is interesting is that if when inserting the field I select the #:1 format, which is an absolute scale it displays 1:40. I know its a feet to inches problem but i can't put my finger on it. Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Also the following link is an issue with autocad 2006 which had the same issue so it may still be a bug.
[Title Mark Scale reads incorrectly](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/autocad-architecture-forum/title-mark-scale-reads-incorrectly/td-p/2014053?nobounce)

[image]

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the properties of the viewport you are referencing?

Comment: <img src="http://i.imgur.com/HxGBggJ.png">

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming?  I don't see anything involving the AutoCAD .NET API, LISP, or even scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding that scale to your drawing scales list. In the command line type _SCALELISTEDIT

You will get this window:

[image]

Click the Add button, and in the Name box type 1" = 40' then below set 1 Paper Units to 40 drawing units.

[image]

Then you should be able to select your viewport, and set the annotation scale to the 1" = 40' scale you just created. The scale listed in the field in you view callout block should now update to match.

If this is a scale regularly used, you will want to add this to your template as well.

Make sure when setting the field for your view block, that you pick 'Use Scale Name'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is true, the label will report correctly now,  however as your screenshot illustrates, you now have a viewport that is at 1"=480' scale.  If I wanted an absolute scale such as inches : Inches these numbers would be correct.  Since i'm using inches in layout and feet in my drawing the scale needs to be 1" = 40'. If you open this scale that you added and replace the 480 with 40 as it should be, then the scale label in the drawing will revert back to 1"=3.33333'.

Comment: Ok, so you are actually drawing in model space a 1:12 scale then. This still works on my end. If you add the scale the same way I show above, but set 1 Paper Units to 40 drawing units, then you can select that scale for your viewport. You just have to make sure that the field you are referencing in your block is 'Use Scale Name' instead of the scale format.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the "Use Scale Name" part of your previous post.  This seems like a good work around.  Thanks